# JavaScript screen positions after collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im tried hide div tag using javascript,But when it collapse, how to screen the exact dive in screen position?

Javascript , css and HTML as follows

```js
  // Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
    $('.box').hide();

    // Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
    // with a click event to toggle the "box" state
    $('.clickme').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function (e) {
            // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box"   elements
            e.preventDefault();

            // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
            $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });

    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#box1").slideToggle('fast');
        $("#box2").slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px/16px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    }

     .clickme {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;}

    }

    .clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clickme">Menu 1</a>
    <span><span class="labelText"><span></span>Number 1</span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <br/>
    <span><span class="labelText"><span></span>Number 2</span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="inputclmsize1" value="" maxlength="50" aria-invalid="false">
    <br>
    <a id="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="clickme">Menu 2</a>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    </div>
```

I added this to jsfiddle with more text data. what i want is, After i clicked menu 1, there is end of submit link. when i click that submit link in menu 1,
automatically menu 2 open. but it not open with correct position to screen.i want to show menu 2 on screen start position. So how to position this?
Thanks you. you can view this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rn4qdyue/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop` of the `parent` and position it at the top position of the element you want at the top. You'll have to factor other values such as offset of parent and margins if you want it to be really precise. You could call it after the `slide` animation. Like this:

```
       $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast', function () {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).position().top - $(this).parent().offset().top - 15
            })
        })
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5o3bL69/1/